# Does anybody knows how to recieve 2nd response(without request) from server after executing some prevoius operation

Tags: jmeter

I need to get 2nd response from server after executing some prevoius operation.
I meen: 1st request(websocket) is sent, that user recieves respond for it,
and only after that for the same user other response(automatically) is sent. This 2nd response I need to derive. Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

What sampler are you using? If it is [JMeter-WebSocketSampler](https://github.com/maciejzaleski/JMeter-WebSocketSampler/), there is `Streaming Connection` option available:

[image: JMeter WebSocket Sampler]

If it's checked the connection won't be closed and will be remaining/shared after first request completion.

Check [WebSocket Testing With Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/websocket-testing-apache-jmeter) guide for detailed sampler description and information on custom sampler implementation if required.

Comment: Yes, I use WebSocketSampler. This problem was eleminated, but now response is sent to other user. And it is impossible to get response by this user (without request). I meen: 1 request from client1 is sent to sever, after that server send response to other client. How can I get this response?